# Как с помощью Tkinter или PyQt вывести в окне картинку по ссылке?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, pyqt4, pyqt5

Доброго вечера суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью Tkinter или PyQt вывести в окне картинку по ссылке?

В Tkinter я знаю лишь PhotoImage который позволяет выводить картинки, но только те которые находятся на компьютере.

Зачем мне это? Хочу сделать что-то на подобии галереи, но что бы фотки подгружались с интернета (те которые я пропишу)

Я только начинаю в GUI разбираться и если кто-то направит на путь истинный, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Связанный вопрос [How to display html using QWebView. Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13384749/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ загрузить данные это использовать библиотеку `urllib`. Для отображения картинки в `PyQt5` можно использовать элемент `QLabel`. После того, как разберетесь с этим, для загрузки данных будет лучше заменить библиотеку `urllib` на `QNetworkAccessManager` что позволит вам загружать данные в фоне, не блокируя GUI пользователя.

Вот простой пример:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
from urllib import request


class URLView(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.urlEdit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.urlEdit.setText('https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png')
        layout.addWidget(self.urlEdit)

        self.imageLabel = Qt.QLabel("No image")
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

        self.loadButton = Qt.QPushButton("Load")
        layout.addWidget(self.loadButton)

        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.on_load)

    def on_load(self):
        print("Load image")
        data = request.urlopen(self.urlEdit.text()).read()
        pixmap = Qt.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(data)
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = URLView()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: чтобы не блокировать GUI в urlopen.read(), можно в отдельном потоке загружать. [Пара примеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/813204/23044), а вот для [tkinter примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723192/23044)

Comment: а можно ли такое сделать для ```QMovie```?

Answer (score 2):

Если делать через `QNetworkAccessManager`, тогда код не слишком изменится:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class URLView(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.urlEdit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.urlEdit.setText('https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png')
        layout.addWidget(self.urlEdit)

        self.imageLabel = Qt.QLabel("No image")
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

        self.loadButton = Qt.QPushButton("Load")
        layout.addWidget(self.loadButton)

        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.on_load)

        self.nam = Qt.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.finish_request)

    def on_load(self):
        print("Load image")

        url = self.urlEdit.text()
        self.nam.get(Qt.QNetworkRequest(Qt.QUrl(url)))

    def finish_request(self, reply):
        img = Qt.QPixmap()
        img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())

        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = URLView()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

---

Хотел добавить что вызов `reply.readAll()` не будет блокировать поток, т.к. данные из запроса уже скачаны.

Comment: можно явно упомянуть в ответе блокирует ли GUI readAll(). Что будет если сервер картинку медленно отдаёт?¶ К удивлению, даже на C++ [пример с QNetworkAccessManager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661222/23044) опрятно (относительно) выглядит.

Comment: Если я правильно понял описание http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished, то ответ по запросу уже скачан и находится в QNetworkReply, поэтому readAll вернет уже загруженные данные

Comment: да, я тоже так думаю. В [`QNetworkReply::finished()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#finished) ещё более явно сказано: *"After this signal is emitted, there will be no more updates to the reply's data or metadata."* (то есть `readAll()` возвращает всё что осталось не блокируя). Но так как это не очевидно и один из ответов содержит `.read()` вызов, который может заморозить GUI на неопределённое время, стоит явно в ответе упомянуть, что `readAll()` не замораживает GUI здесь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без `QNetworkAccessManager` если загрузку и передачу картинки сделать в другом потоке (`QThread`):

```
from urllib import request
from PyQt5 import Qt


class LoadImageThread(Qt.QThread):
    about_new_image = Qt.pyqtSignal(Qt.QPixmap)

    def run(self):
        data = request.urlopen(self.url).read()
        pixmap = Qt.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(data)

        # Передаем картинку с сигналом
        self.about_new_image.emit(pixmap)


class URLView(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.urlEdit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.urlEdit.setText('https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png')
        layout.addWidget(self.urlEdit)

        self.imageLabel = Qt.QLabel("No image")
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

        self.loadButton = Qt.QPushButton("Load")
        layout.addWidget(self.loadButton)

        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.on_load)

        # Создаем объект потока и привязываем его сигнал к слоту установки картинки
        self.thread = LoadImageThread()
        self.thread.about_new_image.connect(self.imageLabel.setPixmap)

        # Пока выполняется загрузка картинки, кнопка недоступна
        self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.loadButton.setEnabled(False))
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.loadButton.setEnabled(True))

    def on_load(self):
        print("Load image")

        # Запускаем поток
        self.thread.url = self.urlEdit.text()
        self.thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = URLView()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: вы несколько раз один и тот же поток запускаете? Что будет если на кнопку несколько раз нажать? Кстати, можно без наследования обойтись и в обычном Питон потоке загружать, а для сигнала любой QObject такой как URLView подойдёт. [Пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/fd292613a51bc55f224b6d74f84fc316)

Comment: Можно, конечно, было питоничьи потоки (или процессы) использовать, но хотелось сделать с сигналом/слотом. А start() будет порождать новый поток, но будет ожидание завершения предыдущего (через print проверил). Кроме того, можно через интерфейс ограничение сделать, ответе это покажу

Comment: `threading.Thread` можно только один раз запустить. Для QThread если поток уже запущен, вызов `start()` ничего не делает: If ["the thread is already running, this function does nothing."](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#start)

Comment: да и [пример, который я привёл,](https://gist.github.com/zed/fd292613a51bc55f224b6d74f84fc316) использует сигналы (их можно использовать даже из Python потоков). Посмотрите `server_started`, `request_finished`.

Comment: Что и подтвердилось на практике. Пример у вас интересный :) Немного смущает, что сигнал объекта вызывает его же метод, ну и то, что этот объект в другой поток отправляется :)

Comment: вызов `w.display()` в другом потоке (отличном от потока, который сигнал отправил). Отправлять сигналы из других потоков можно, но GUI элементы дёргать из чужих потоков нельзя (если thread affinity не менять), поэтому `widget.signal.emit()` можно вызвать, а `widget.gui_method` нельзя (если только gui_method() явно не документирован, что он thread-safe).

Comment: Понял, это логично